# Example algolia and Symfony

Tags: symfony, algolia

I use this documentation for install algolia: 
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/symfony/setup/

this configuration is already done:

```
composer require algolia/algolia-search-bundle
```

And

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Algolia\AlgoliaSearchBundle\AlgoliaAlgoliaSearchBundle(),
);
```

configuration.yml:

```
algolia:
    application_id: YOUR_APP_ID
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY
```

but I don't understand , I need a example for implementation in my project.
Please your help

Comment: What part didn't work for you?

Comment: already install the bundle and configure but I do not know how to use it in my project

Comment: Did you add the entity annotations?

Comment: Yes, This section https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/symfony/mapping-entities-to-algolia-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

1-) you should install `algolia-search-bundle` with `Composer`;

`composer require algolia/algolia-search-bundle`

2-) add line this -> `Algolia\AlgoliaSearchBundle\AlgoliaAlgoliaSearchBundle()` at `app/AppKernel.php` file into `$bundles` array.

3-)you should add your api keys at `app/config/config.yml` file;

`algolia:
    application_id: YOUR_APP_ID
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY`

That's enough.

Comment: If that is clear to me. My question is after that how to use the bundle. maybe I was not clear